# How to get achievements notification popup for Ajax Callbacks?

Tags: 7, ajax

I'm using the [Achievements](https://www.drupal.org/project/achievements) module to award the badges to users on certain actions.

In the following example user will get badges after posting 5 and 10 comments.

```
function MYMODULE_comment_insert($comment) {
  $current_count = achievements_storage_get('comment-count', $comment->uid) + 1;
  achievements_storage_set('comment-count', $current_count, $comment->uid);

  foreach (array(5,10) as $count) {
    if ($current_count == $count) {
      achievements_unlocked('comment-count-' . $count, $comment->uid);
    }
  }
}
```

The above code is working, user is able to achieve badge after posting 5 comments but since the comment form is being submitted through AJAX, the rewarded achievements notification popup is not being shown until page refresh.

So how can I show achievement notification popup for Ajax callbacks? Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments or your own code for ajaxify comments?

Comment: @MariaKvitova No I'm using [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) and [Drupal Wall](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal_wall) modules which uses Ajax. Thanks

Comment: Could you tell what version of Drupal wall do you use? I tried 7.x-2.7 it doesn't seem to work :( You can find that message appears from hook_page_alter http://cgit.drupalcode.org/achievements/tree/achievements.module?h=7.x-1.x#n709 So you can use it in your ajax-callback and return message as ajax-command. Unfortunately I can't give you more details, because I couldn't force Drupal Wall to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another try at this (various assumptions follow):

- The whole thing should run through the Wall module's code, since this is the base for any other interaction happening.
- By means of the Form API and AJAX callbacks, there is a possible entry point. This is to wrap the submit callback for the _drupal_wall_comment_post_form into another callback that will make sure the Achievements' related elements are updated.
- The steps in this process would be:

  1. Use hook_form_alter to modify `_drupal_wall_comment_post_form`
  2. Modify `_drupal_wall_comment_post_form` by hijacking the ajax callback for the wall comment submissions: 
     `$form['drupal_wall_submit']['#ajax']['callback'] =>_your_custom_wall_ajax_callback`
  3. Wrap the original callback in your ajax callback and extend it to trigger the Achievements popup functionality using the [Ajax framework commands](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7) family:

     ```
     function _your_custom_wall_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {  
       $wall_wrapper = $form['drupal_wall_submit']['#ajax']['wrapper'];
       $wall_content = _drupal_wall_comment_ajax_form_post($form, $form_state);
       $commands = array();
       $commands[] = ajax_command_replace($wall_wrapper, $wall_content);

       // This is where you can write ajax commands to trigger Achievements functionality
       $commands[] = ajax_command_*();

       return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
     }
     ```

Hope this brings you a step further!

Comment: You are welcome! It would be great to update your question with things you tried and didn't work, what would you say? Cheers

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to add a rule for when a user post a comment and then do your thing

[image]

After creating the rule you can set conditions and actions, so you can check for the comment count and then act accordingly